# ArrayList Iterator does not display any data

Tags: java, oop, arraylist, iterator, thread-safety

I am trying to display an ArrayList using Iterator. I am taking a studentInfo class which has getter-setter methods for various fname, lname, instName, etc. However, when I am calling the displaydata() method from main(), it does not display any data. I verified that ArrayList is being populated.

Another piece of code is a thread that accepts the data from a file and reads into arraylist by addStudentData() method.

```
interface inf_regStore {
    public void displayData();
public void addStudentData(String fname, String lname, String instName, int courseNo);
}

public class registrationStore implements inf_regStore{
    // create data structure and store the objects using vector or arraylist 


   public static ArrayList<studentInfo> stud = new ArrayList<studentInfo>();

    studentInfo sinfo;
    public void addStudentData(String fname, String lname, String instName, int courseNo)
    {
        sinfo = new studentInfo(fname, lname, instName, courseNo);
        stud.add(sinfo);
        System.out.println("Student Added\n");
    }


public void displayData(){
        Iterator<studentInfo> disp = stud.iterator();
        while(disp.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(disp.next().getFname());
            System.out.println(disp.next().getLname());
            System.out.println(disp.next().getInstName());
            System.out.println(disp.next().getCourseNo());
            System.out.println("Student Displayed\n");
        }
        //System.out.println("Student Displayed\n");
}

}
```

---

```
interface inf_readFile{
    public void readFile();
 }

// this is a thread class 
public class fileReader implements Runnable{
    // It reads the data file 
    BufferedReader input;
    registrationStore rs = new registrationStore();
    public fileReader() {
        try{
        File file = new File("dataFile.txt");
        input = new  BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("File Not Found!");
    }
}

public void run(){
    readFile();
}

public void readFile(){

    try{

         String strline; 
         while((strline=input.readLine()) !=null){

                String[] details = strline.split(" ");
                //System.out.println(details[0]);
                rs.addStudentData(details[0], details[1], details[2], Integer.parseInt(details[3]));

        }

         input.close();

    }
    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

Edit 1: Got the Solution. Since I am working with the threads, I need to use a threadsafe data structure. Changed Arraylist into a Vector.

Comment: Couple of notes: respect the Java naming conventions (classes starting with an uppercase letter, containing no underscore, fields and methods without abbreviations: getFirstName(), getLastName()); use the foreach loop which would make this kind of bug impossible, indent your code correctly; your `stud` field should not be static (and should be named `studentList`): you want every registration store to have its own list of students.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call disp.next() once time;

```
        Iterator<studentInfo> disp = stud.iterator();
        while(disp.hasNext()){
            studentInfo info = disp.next();
            System.out.println(info.getFname());
            System.out.println(info.getLname());
            System.out.println(info.getInstName());
            System.out.println(info.getCourseNo());
            System.out.println("Student Displayed\n");
        }
```

Comment: Still it doesnt let me print the data.

Comment: @denizen: that tells us squat. If you're having problem with new code, show the code, and describe *in detail* your problems or errors encountered.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: I have edited the code again. Can you please go through it and tell me what might me the problem?

Comment: @denizen: yes, your current code ***still has the same problematic code***. You've implemented none of our recommendations, at least none that I can see. You still appear to be calling `next()` multiple times in your while loop despite many of us telling you not to. Why?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: I dint get you. Can you be more specific?

Comment: @denizen: I'm sorry if I sound a bit harsh, but really? Please read my answer. Please read Thanh's answer above. Please read enthu's answer, please read Dave Smith's answer. Please show that you've read  any and all answers. It's all spelled out for you.

Answer (score 3):

You're calling `disp.next()` way too many times. You just call it ***once*** within your while loop to get the object, and then extract the info from the object obtained. This makes sense since a call to `disp.next()` should pair one-to-one with a call to `disp.hasNext()`, else you're calling `next()` without the safety of knowing if `hasNext()` is still true.

i.e.,

```
public void displayData(){
    Iterator<studentInfo> disp = stud.iterator();
    while(disp.hasNext()){
        studentInfo sInfo = disp.next();
        System.out.println(sInfo.getFname());
        System.out.println(sInfo.getLname());
        System.out.println(sInfo.getInstName());
        System.out.println(sInfo.getCourseNo());
        System.out.println("Student Displayed\n");
    }
}
```

As an aside, you will want to learn and follow Java naming conventions. Please note that class, interface, and enum names all begin with an upper-case letter while variable and method names all begin with a lower-case letter. Following these conventions will make your code easier for others (us!) to understand and follow it.

Answer (score 0):

you are calling disp.next() many times so you are getting the data of different object what you have to do is use the for-each or call .iterator only one time

like

```
     while(disp.hasNext()){
            studentInfo sInfo = disp.next();
             System.out.println(sInfo.getFname());
            System.out.println(sInfo.getLname());
            System.out.println(sInfo.getInstName());
            System.out.println(sInfo.getCourseNo());
            System.out.println("Student Displayed\n");
}
```

or

```
for(String sInfo : stud ){
    System.out.println(sInfo.getFname());
                System.out.println(sInfo.getLname());
                System.out.println(sInfo.getInstName());
                System.out.println(sInfo.getCourseNo());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

each time you call `disp.next()` the iterator move forward a step, you should call disp.next() once, and use a local variable to hold it

```
StudentInfo info = disp.next();
// then use the info instance
```